# How can I select ways that have missing access parameters "[key]=Not Specified"?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, data-quality

Follow up to [How can I programmatically identify missing sidewalks in OpenStreetMap data?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/181499/36886). I've noticed that a number of streets and roads in a region I'm interested in are missing pedestrian access when they have sidewalks, and this is affecting [pedestrian Mapbox directions](https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api/directions/).

How can I find ways in Overpass Turbo that are missing this access parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [Overpass API language guide](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide), specifically the section about [negation](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide#Negation).

Not sure what tags Mapbox directions is looking for. Here is an example query for retrieving various roads missing a sidewalk=* key:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
way["highway"~"primary|secondary|tertiary|residential|unclassified|service"]["sidewalk"!~"."]({{bbox}});
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

You can view the [result on overpass turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/eEr).

Comment: Thanks for the example. I changed it to find missing `foot` access.
There are still a number of streets in my area that are failing.  http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/eEV

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to add a foot tag to every way. Usually foot access should be the default for most highway classes except for motorway. See the [implicit default values](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_tags_for_routing/Access-Restrictions). It might be possible that Mapbox directions uses slightly different defaults, though. Still, adding foot to every way seems wrong.

Comment: Hmm... I didn't know about the defaults. Thanks for sharing. It seems there is a divergence, since the road that wasn't working with Mapbox directions was tagged `highway=trunk` which *should* have default ped `access=yes`

Comment: Personally I can't understand why trunk has default foot access. Every trunk road (in Germany) that I know doesn't have foot access. But this might be different from country to country. Maybe Mapbox decided to change this default which seems reasonable to me.